# excel file as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and have a question about how to read an excel file.
 I have an excel file with the format below:

```
item     Type    Target   choice1    choice2    
 1       book    pen       pencil      m 
 .        .       .         .          .
 .        .       .         .          .
 n=120
```

And I wanted to write Python code that read and print the excel file as a dictionary as we can see below:

```
trials = {"trial1":["book", "pen", "pencil"]}
```

and my goal is to be able to recall it in the code as below:

```
trial1_target = trials["trial1"][0] 
trial1_choice1 = trials["trial1"][1] 
trial1_choice2 = trials["trial"][2]
```

I tried to implement the code, in the below structure but I got the wrong format. Do you have any suggestion for me?

```
import xlrd
file='se_de.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
worksheet.cell(0,4)

Lst=list()
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    Lst.append("Trial"+str(row)+":["+worksheet.cell(row,1)++worksheet.cell(row,2)+worksheet.cell(row,3)"]")
```

All your comments are appreciated in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the "wrong" format you got?

Comment: I edited my question. You were completely right. I needed to recall is as Trial1_target= trial[trial1][0] and Trial1_ch1= trial[trial1][1] and Trial1_ch2= trial[trial1][2] but I dont know why my code dosent work as it should be

Comment: The wrong format is: when I printed it as a list I don't have access to each individual cell rather I read whole the line in the one structure. That means I get: "trial1":["book", "pen", "pencil"] but when I type  trials["trial1"][0]  instead of "pen" it gives me trial1":["book", "pen", "pencil"] .

Comment: I removed comment after you address it in an edit. If I understand correctly, you're currently building the dictionary as an actual string, so Python won't treat this as a dictionary. Inside your `for` loop, first build the list so like `temp_list = [worksheet.cell(row,1), worksheet.cell(row,2,..]`. Then create the trail name `trial_name = "Trial" + str(row)`. Finally. `Lst.append({trial_name: temp_list})`. You then create a valid dictionary. You could condense these steps. I think that gives you what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, you last comment confirms the issue. I'll write up in an answer so it's clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment. considering your comments what I get is as below: {'Trial1': [empty:'', text:u'tr\xe9sor', text:u'cachette']}  that means it does not recognize the french alphabets that includes (é) in the excel file. The second problem is if I wanted to print    trials["trial1"][0] it gives me  text:u'banane'. I don't know how to eliminate that additional Unicode sign. Do you please have any advice for me?

Comment: Please see my answer as it is more complete and we can discuss a specific issue there. I don't know what API this is, but are you sure that the output was correct before, other than the fact that you couldn't use it as a dictionary? I'm guessing you need something like `worksheet.cell(row, 1).value` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. even using worksheet.cell(row, 1).value I have the same problem. The problem is I could not use it as a dictionary to be able to access each cell separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are not building valid data structures (lists and dictionaries) but are instead concatenating a bunch of string objects together. This means that Python will just treat the final output as a list of strings. I have broken it down into a number of stages with comments so that you can see how to build the structure.

```
# Firstly, the desired structure is a dictionary, not a list, so Lst.append()
# Will never give you the desired output. Create an empty dictionary instead
trials = {}

for row_num in range(1, worksheet.nrows):

    # First build the list portion
    data_list = [worksheet.cell(row_num, 1), worksheet.cell(row_num, 2),
                 worksheet.cell(row_num, 3)]

    # Generate the key
    key = "Trial{}".format(row_num)

    # Add the key, value pair to the dictionary
    trials[key] = data_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It really does the job that I wanted to do before, except that some words in the excel file that I have are in French. And I could see that with this code it prints strongly: trials['Trial149'][1]   text:u'm\xe9fiance' instead of "méfiance" plus it carries a Unicode u. How can I overcome these two problems, please? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: That depends on where you're looking at this output. If you were to `print` the output then it may appear correctly. You will have to look into `encode` and `decode`, and I think Python 2 will treat it differently to Python 3 too.

Comment: You have since raised the encoding issue as another question. If my answer address the immediate problem in _this_ question, I would appreciate you considering [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).